# PHP base64_decode does not work in equivalent Coldfusion code

Tags: php, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have this code in PHP:

```
<?php
$decodedSecret = base64_decode("OWOMg2gnaSx1nukAM6SN2vxedfY1yLPONvcTKbhDv7I");
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha512", "1|2481632|1425387916|GET|/api/transaction/read?spaceId=12&id=1", $decodedSecret, true));
?>
```

and tried to translate it in Coldfusion like this:

```
local.secret = toBase64( 'OWOMg2gnaSx1nukAM6SN2vxedfY1yLPONvcTKbhDv7I' );
local.hmacHex = hmac( '1|2481632|1425387916|GET|/api/transaction/read?spaceId=12&id=1', local.secret, 'HMACSHA512' );
local.base64 = binaryEncode( binaryDecode( local.hmacHex, "hex"), "base64" );
```

However, for some reason, this is not working and I suspect that the problem is this part:

```
local.secret = toBase64( 'OWOMg2gnaSx1nukAM6SN2vxedfY1yLPONvcTKbhDv7I' );
```

that does not seem to be equivalent to this PHP code:

```
$decodedSecret = base64_decode("OWOMg2gnaSx1nukAM6SN2vxedfY1yLPONvcTKbhDv7I");
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

UPDATE:

After Alex's suggestion, I used the following code snippet to achieve the goal of replicating the PHP results in Coldfusion.

```
local.secret = toBinary( 'OWOMg2gnaSx1nukAM6SN2vxedfY1yLPONvcTKbhDv7I=' );
local.hmacHex = hmac( '1|2481632|1425387916|GET|/api/transaction/read?spaceId=12&id=1', local.secret, 'HMACSHA512', 'utf-8' );
local.strBase64 = toBase64( binaryDecode( local.hmacHex, "hex" ) );
```

Unfortunatelly, `toString(toBinary('OWOMg2gnaSx1nukAM6SN2vxedfY1yLPONvcTKbhDv7I'))` didn't work for the secret (that is why I used only `toBinary()`), as hmac would return a different result than the expected one. This probably means that hmac deals differently with binaries than with strings, for anyone interested out there.

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What debugging have you done? What exactly happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc. See also [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work).

Comment: `I suspect that the problem is this part`...because? Give an explanation and/or evidence for your reasoning.

Comment: I know nothing about ColdFusion, but `base64_decode` goes *from* base64 *to* raw text; so `toBase64` sounds like the wrong function. Is there a corresponding `fromBase64`?

Comment: @ADyson Not working in this case means not producing the same output. If you try both codes in an online compiler/interpreter, you will get different results for the 2 bottom commands I shared.

Comment: @IMSoP Apparently, it looks like this has something to do with it, but I can't find a way to figure it out. I tried everything I can think of, that is why I was wondering if anyone else has any ideas. And to answer your (very good) question, there is nothing equivalent to fromBase64 that I know of, besides binaryDecode, that throws an error when used.

Comment: `base64_decode(x)` would be `toString(toBinary(x))` in ColdFusion. However, `hmac()` supports byte array for the key, so `toBinary()` should be sufficient. You can also simplify the last line to `local.base64 = toBase64(binaryDecode(local.hmacHex, "hex"))` for the same reason.

Comment: @Alex Thank you so much for your comment! It helped me figure out a way to replicate the PHP result in Coldfusion. I will update the question with the code I used to finally make it work, but I think you should post your comment as an answer so that I can select it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Was just working with this stuff.  You want toBinary() if you're wanting to create a binary from base 64 encoded string data.

```
<cfset bData = toBinary(form.base64Data) />
<cfcontent variable=bData type="application/pdf" />
```

I had just built a simple form to paste my Base64 data and just get the binary.  (I know it's PDF content, hence the MIME type.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Will but it seems that toBinary does not produce the same output as the base64_decode. I used it as my first try to solve this, but I must be missing something since it is not really doing the same thing as the PHP code.